# Eilenberg-Zilber via acyclic models

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am reading Kottke's notes on Eilenberg-Zilber and its proof via acyclic models: https://ckottke.ncf.edu/docs/acyclic.pdf

One aspect of the proof that eludes me is why, on page 3, this relationship holds:

[image]

I understand that the 2 middle terms cancel out, but why would $\partial \partial i_p \times i_q$ be $0$? It is certainly $0 \times i_q$, but we do not assume at any point that this should be $0$ as a chain...

Comment: See Proposition 1.3 p.2: $a\times b$ is defined as $\times(a\otimes b).$